# How to activate Rails with Passenger and Apache on CentOs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I've been struggling with this for hours. It's the first time that I try to establish a server.

I have rails, passenger and apache installed.
In the httpd.conf here is what I wrote:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
# Here I wrote the IP address, since I still did not manage the DNS
Listen ##.##.##.94:80
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName ##.##.##.94:80 # Do I need this?

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-4.0.59/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-4.0.59
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName ##.##.##.##
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/blah_blah/public_html/public
      <Directory  /var/www/blah_blah/public_html>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The last section was produced by passenger (I did not! copy it from the instructions :-) ).

When I go to the IP address I get an error that the page was not found.

I have rails running with "rails s". Before that I reloaded the server and restarted it for the config file to take effect.
Also, I granted apache user permission to the www folder.

What is the problem?

I even tried to put an index.html file in the public folder of rail and tried to go there, but failed.

BTW - when I do it from the console:

```
wget http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

I get a 200 response which means that it is OK.

Where is the fault?

Comment: both these folders need to be the same.

 DocumentRoot /var/www/blah_blah/public_html/public
      <Directory  /var/www/blah_blah/public_html/public>

Comment: I tried it also. Doesn't work.

Comment: try removing the ServerName as well. Since it blank its better if nots there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change the port:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
```

Because when you run `rails s` it run on port 3000.